# How to process unstructured text data by hadoop(PIG/MapReduce)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am working on unstructured text file .i wanna process it by hadoop
but i getting problem to extract required data from file .pls help on it.

my file looks like:
[image]

and i am expecting output like;

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste, don't use screenshots. That includes the Pig code you've written

Answer (score 0):

As I known, the invalid data could be ignored by `MapReduce`, at least, you can implement your own `map` to do that.

For example, the delimiter is `\n`, each line with specified format should be accepted, otherwise will be ignored. In this case, each line contains 6 columns separated by space should be treated normal.

`//map
    @Override
    public void map(K key, V value, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
      // value contains line content,
      // verify value, only those valid lines should be accepted.
    }`

Comment: Thank you Keith  for your time to provide me helping hand. Keith Map Reduce will be best choice as always but i want reduce too much coding stuff and want to implement in PIG side.If you share you idea in pig then it will gd also :)

Comment: I'm afraid you are right. I would advise you to use PIG if I'd already known what PIG is. PIG is professional in handling this and more convenient. However, I'm still new to PIG and I'm going to learn more about it. Happy journey.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RANK in PIG to filter your headers. Try this.

```
A = LOAD 'file' as (line:chararray);
B = RANK A;
C = FILTER B BY rank_A > 5;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE line;
DUMP D;
```

Comment: Thanks Vignesh,i tried it is working but what if scenario is like below.Please check my below post as i can not post in comment.